# React typescript getting error as `Type '() => JSX.Element | undefined'`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, type-definition

Error:

```
Type '() => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.ts(2322)
```

code:

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { fetchSingleCocktail } from "../redux/features/cocktailSlice";
import { AppDispatch, RootState } from "../redux/store";

export type ingredientsProps = {
  strIngredient1: string|null;
  strIngredient2: string|null;
  strIngredient3: string | null;
  strIngredient4: string | null;
  strIngredient5: string | null;
}

export type ViewCockTailPros = {
  name: string;
  image: string;
  info: string;
  category: string;
  glass: string;
  instructions: string;
  ingredients:ingredientsProps[]
}

const SingleCocktail:FC = () => {
  const { cocktail } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.app);
  const [modifiedCocktail, setModifiedCocktail] = useState<ViewCockTailPros|null>();
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchSingleCocktail({id}))
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cocktail && cocktail.length > 0) {
      const {
        strDrink: name,
        strDrinkThumb: image,
        strAlcoholic: info,
        strCategory: category,
        strGlass: glass,
        strInstructions: instructions,
        strIngredient1,
        strIngredient2,
        strIngredient3,
        strIngredient4,
        strIngredient5
      } = cocktail[0];
      
      const ingredients = [strIngredient1, strIngredient2, strIngredient3, strIngredient4, strIngredient5];
      const newCocktail = { name, image, info, category, glass, instructions, ingredients };
      setModifiedCocktail(newCocktail);
    } else {
      setModifiedCocktail(null);
    }
  }, [cocktail]);

  if (!modifiedCocktail) {
      return <h2 className="section-title">No cocktail to display</h2>
  }

  if (modifiedCocktail) { 
    const { name, image, category, info, glass, instructions, ingredients } = modifiedCocktail as ViewCockTailPros;
    return (
        <>
        <section className="section cocktail-section">
                <Link to={"/"}>
                  <button className="btn btn-danger" style={{marginTop:"2rem"}}>Go Back</button>
                </Link>
                <h2 className="section-title">{name}</h2>
                <div className="drink">
                  <img src={image} alt={name} />
                  <div className="drink-info">
                    <p>
                      <span className="drink-data">Name:</span> {name}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <span className="drink-data">Category:</span> {category}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <span className="drink-data">Info:</span> {info}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <span className="drink-data">Glass:</span> {glass}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <span className="drink-data">Instructions:</span> {instructions}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      <span className="drink-data">Ingredents</span> 
                      {ingredients && ingredients.map((item:any, index:number) => {
                        return item ? <span key={index}>{item}</span>:null
                      })}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
        </section>
        </>
      ) 
  }
}

export default SingleCocktail
```

any one please help me?

Comment: You don't need to check if `modifiedCocktail` is truthy after you check it's falsey since you return in the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statements are constructed in a way that potentially none of them can be executed, thus function can return `undefined`.

Add `return null;` at the end of the component to ensure proper return type.

Comment: I am not sure I understood this. Atleast one of them **will** run right?

Comment: We know this, but TypeScript doesn't - TS static analyzer just sees that function has two if clauses at the end of its body, which means that there is theoretical possibility that none of them will be executed - and function will return `undefined`.

Comment: TS compiler has limited heuristics (which is not necessarily bad thing, for example it lowers CPU usage when static analyzing), this is one of the cases when type is not fully inferred from the code.

Comment: Cool get it. What confuses me is it works here : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-njegoh?file=/src/Test.tsx

Comment: Do you have the same TypeScript version?